# How to send files over Internet not LAN?

Tags: python, file-transfer

So, me and my friend just wanted to try creating our own personal chat application in python I started by trying to make a CLI application first, I googled a few things but I am unable to find out how to send files over Internet . There are a lot of ways to send it over LAN but me and my friend are on different networks so that won't work. I can't seem to find a way to do it over the internet. I am new to networking so please pardon if I have made any mistake. Here's the code I have to transfer files over LAN:

**client.py**

```
import socket
from threading import Thread
from datetime import datetime

# server's IP address
# if the server is not on this machine, 
# put the private (network) IP address (e.g 192.168.1.2)
SERVER_HOST = input("Server IP : ")
SERVER_PORT = 5002 # server's port
separator_token = "<SEP>" # we will use this to separate the client name & message

# initialize TCP socket
s = socket.socket()
print(f"[*] Connecting to {SERVER_HOST}:{SERVER_PORT}...")
# connect to the server
s.connect((SERVER_HOST, SERVER_PORT))
print("[+] Connected.")
# prompt the client for a name
name = input("Enter your name: ")
def listen_for_messages():
    while True:
        message = s.recv(1024).decode()
        print("\n" + message)

# make a thread that listens for messages to this client & print them
t = Thread(target=listen_for_messages)
# make the thread daemon so it ends whenever the main thread ends
t.daemon = True
# start the thread
t.start()
while True:
    # input message we want to send to the server
    to_send =  input()
    # a way to exit the program
    if to_send.lower() == 'q':
        break
    # add the datetime, name & the color of the sender
    date_now = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') 
    to_send = f"[{date_now}] {name}{separator_token}{to_send}"
    # finally, send the message
    s.send(to_send.encode())

# close the socket
s.close()
```

**server.py**

```
import socket
from threading import Thread

# server's IP address
SERVER_HOST = "0.0.0.0"
SERVER_PORT = 5002 # port we want to use
separator_token = "<SEP>" # we will use this to separate the client name & message

# initialize list/set of all connected client's sockets
client_sockets = set()
# create a TCP socket
s = socket.socket()
# make the port as reusable port
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
# bind the socket to the address we specified
s.bind((SERVER_HOST, SERVER_PORT))
# listen for upcoming connections
s.listen(5)
print(f"[*] Listening as {SERVER_HOST}:{SERVER_PORT}")
def listen_for_client(cs):
    """
    This function keep listening for a message from `cs` socket
    Whenever a message is received, broadcast it to all other connected clients
    """
    while True:
        try:
            # keep listening for a message from `cs` socket
            msg = cs.recv(1024).decode()
        except Exception as e:
            # client no longer connected
            # remove it from the set
            print(f"[!] Error: {e}")
            client_sockets.remove(cs)
        else:
            # if we received a message, replace the <SEP> 
            # token with ": " for nice printing
            msg = msg.replace(separator_token, ": ")
        # iterate over all connected sockets
        for client_socket in client_sockets:
            # and send the message
            client_socket.send(msg.encode())

while True:
    # we keep listening for new connections all the time
    client_socket, client_address = s.accept()
    print(f"[+] {client_address} connected.")
    # add the new connected client to connected sockets
    client_sockets.add(client_socket)
    # start a new thread that listens for each client's messages
    t = Thread(target=listen_for_client, args=(client_socket,))
    # make the thread daemon so it ends whenever the main thread ends
    t.daemon = True
    # start the thread
    t.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. The issue is the network setup.

I assume you both have typical setups, so you are both behind NAT (network address translation). Other chat apps use a server that you can both connect to. If you put your friend's IP address you will try to open a connection to the router which likely won't answer.

One hack is to setup port forwarding on one of your routers. Say 5002, from your example, and forward all incoming traffic to the right local machine. This should get you running, but I agree it's not a easy thing to get working. An easier setup would be to use upnp which sets up the port forwarding rules automatically, but I don't know which package would do that (there must be one somewhere).

Another way would be to switch to ipv6, if your providers support it. Because of the increase in address space it's common to give out ipv6 ranges to customers, so that local machines can have public ipv6 addresses, which you can use to connect to. Here packages should be routed correctly, but firewalls might interfere.

Yet another hack, would be to bypass routers entirely and plug your machine directly into your uplink connection. This depends on your provider and network setup. This won't work if you have a router that also acts as a modem to connect over TV cable or telephone wires.

Answer (score 0):

Diclaimer: this may not be a true answer (at least it is not the expected one), but it could not fit in a comment.

Luckily you gave some context about your real problem! Because it is neither a Python question nor a file transfer one. It is about how to exchange data between 2 private networks each protected with Network Address Translation by their ISP router. And there is no simple and direct answer, only possible workaround.

In fact the correct solution would be that either you or a friend of yours use a (virtual) machine *in the cloud* and installs the server there. That way the server woud have a true address and could easily be accessed from any of your clients. It has some drawback and pitfalls because you now have an application publicly accessible and always up, so security has to be considered...

The possible workarounds depends on your ISP routers. Some allow to configure a local address to be a DMZ that is an address that is accessible from both the internet and the rest of your LAN but only on certain ports. The rationale behind is to reduce as much as possible the attack surface: the machine in the DMZ will be vulnerable, but it should not contain sensitive data and should be easy to rebuild from scratch if compromised. But it only makes sense if you (or one of your friends) can dedicate a physical machine (raspberry or equivalent are not so expensive). Others allow to configure a special port to be automatically routed to an internal address. You lose the security benefit of a DMZ but no longer need to dedicate anything.

Unfortunately, as I initialy said, I have no code fix to propose because the probem is not there, nor any direct solution because the workarounds really depend on your ISP routers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Serge, I red the article on port forwarding on Wikipedia(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) but I can't seem to figure out which port forwarding to do. Local, Remote Or Dynamic? Can you please help me with that?

Comment: @Teslestien: the paragraph on types of port forwarding is mainly about ssh. It is not your current concern. What you need is the doc for your ISP router.